# What it would take to enable Info Path on our SharePoint server

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, infopath

Could anyone please tell me what it would take to enable Info Path on our SharePoint server along with the pros, cons, and/or risks associated with doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site collection feature" to work with info path forms and also Please check the State service is running and service application is created or not.

you can follow this link for you info path form publishing http://www.appvity.com/blogs/post/2013/06/16/How-to-configure-and-publish-InfoPath-to-SharePoint-2013.aspx

you can read pros and cons about info path forms [Pros and cons](https://a2zmoss.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/pros-and-cons-using-infopath-over-aspx-pages/)